# How inner text from node ignoring text of child nodes using HtmlAgilityPack in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

```html
<div><div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd"><div><div><div class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd"><span class="r0bn4c rQMQod">12-May-2015</span><span class="r0bn4c rQMQod"> � </span>Servante. The Switch. 52 Shades of Red - V3. Flight. The Dream Act. Gone Deck. 52 Shades of Red - V2. Selenium Shift. Cloud 9. S.S.S. 2015�...<span class="BNeawe"><a href="/url?q=https://www.murphysmagic.com/shinlim/52v3/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjv3OGTzefoAhXFH7cAHZmtBbAQ0gIwAHoECAYQAw&amp;usg=AOvVaw3tTmn5G0GOj4J2HVDzTGzq"><span class="XLloXe AP7Wnd">52 Shades of Red V3</span></a></span> � <span class="BNeawe"><a href="/url?q=https://www.murphysmagic.com/shinlim/gonedeck/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjv3OGTzefoAhXFH7cAHZmtBbAQ0gIwAHoECAYQBA&amp;usg=AOvVaw073_Qy3kyDroW9a2C1HqZ7"><span class="XLloXe AP7Wnd">Gone Deck</span></a></span> � <span class="BNeawe"><a href="/url?q=https://www.murphysmagic.com/shinlim/dreamact/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjv3OGTzefoAhXFH7cAHZmtBbAQ0gIwAHoECAYQBQ&amp;usg=AOvVaw0a2sOSXHy75xYz_dbt4GY6"><span class="XLloXe AP7Wnd">The Dream Act</span></a></span> � <span class="BNeawe"><a href="/url?q=https://www.murphysmagic.com/shinlim/flashdeck2/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=2ahUKEwjv3OGTzefoAhXFH7cAHZmtBbAQ0gIwAHoECAYQBg&amp;usg=AOvVaw1KXgysC5jMf3aQWMoBLelC"><span class="XLloXe AP7Wnd">Flash Deck Switch 2.0</span></a></span></div></div></div></div></div>
```

I want to get which is circled in picture using, text have parent, if i select the node on the base of parent div "class="BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd"" this html dived in two node further. 1si node irrelevant to me, and text which i want to get is inside 2nd node